# How do I solve a timeout when trying to add a node to my Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, nodes

I am trying to add a node to my (currently running) Kubernetes cluster.
When I run the kubeadm join command, I get the following error:

```
[WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker 
cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd".  
Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server:  
Get "https://159.65.40.41:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s":  
net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

here is a snippet from the stack trace

```
I0917 16:06:58.162180    2714 token.go:215] [discovery] Failed to request cluster-info, will try again: Get "https://*redacted*:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

What does this mean and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that I had a firewall installed on my server

I have added port 6443 per instructions found here ([Kubeadm join failed : Failed to request cluster-info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243353/kubeadm-join-failed-failed-to-request-cluster-info)) and all is well!